# Pass parameter into controller from select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, parameter-passing

Here is my view:

```
 <%= form_tag({ :action => "display"}, :method => "get") do %>
   <%= select(:music, :type, MusType::TYPES,  {:include_blank => true}) %>
```

Here is my array constant in the model:

```
  class MusType < ActiveRecord::Base
      TYPES = ['Jazz','Rock','Blues']
  end
```

My select menu draws values out of an array.  How do I pass the selected value into the controller as a parameter after the submit button is pressed?

Comment: By adding a form and a submit button? What exactly are you trying to do? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Well it is a search form.  The parameters will determine which data get returned from the database.

Comment: shouldn't the 2nd line be a select_tag instead of just select?

Comment: You should just get a `music` parameter passed in once the submit button is pressed.  Not sure what this question is asking.....

Comment: @jstim No, they have a `select` helper too: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below.
**view code**

```
<%= form_tag(:url => {:controller => "mycontroller" :action => "display"}, :method => "get") do %>
   <%= select_tag(:music, :type, MusType::TYPES,  {:include_blank => true}) %>
   <%= submit_tag "Search", :id => 'search' %>
<% end %>
```

**read the selected value in mycontroller.rb**

```
def display
   value = params[:music][:type]
   // do something with value
end
```